# Orientdb size() returning different result from inside IF()

Tags: methods, conditional-statements, orientdb

This example is using the Tolkien-Arda sample database and batch mode. The following script

```
LET $1 = SELECT expand(bothE(Begets)) FROM Creature WHERE uniquename='hildigrimTook';
LET $2 = SELECT expand(bothE(Begets)) FROM Creature WHERE uniquename='adalgrimTook';
SELECT INTERSECT($1, $2).size();
```

Returns 7 (I've added extras, I think the default would be 2)

However when used in the full script, size() seems to return 0 so it always creates a new edge

```
LET $1 = SELECT expand(bothE(Begets)) FROM Creature WHERE uniquename='hildigrimTook';
LET $2 = SELECT expand(bothE(Begets)) FROM Creature WHERE uniquename='adalgrimTook';
LET $3 = SELECT INTERSECT($1, $2);
LET $4 = CREATE EDGE Begets FROM (SELECT FROM Creature WHERE uniquename='hildigrimTook') TO (SELECT FROM Creature WHERE uniquename='adalgrimTook');
IF($3.size() > 0) {
    return 'Already present';
}
IF($3.size() == 0) {
    return $4;
}
```

This script is supposed to check for edges between hildigrimTook and adalgrimTook and create an edge if it does not already exist.  It seems that INTERSECT($1, $2).size() is returning 0 when called from inside the IF() statement but returns 7 when used as part of a SELECT.

I have tried

```
LET $1 = SELECT expand(bothE(Begets)) FROM Creature WHERE uniquename='hildigrimTook';
LET $2 = SELECT expand(bothE(Begets)) FROM Creature WHERE uniquename='adalgrimTook';
LET $3 = SELECT INTERSECT($1, $2);
SELECT $3.size()
```

But this too returns 0.  I've also done

```
LET $1 = SELECT expand(bothE(Begets)) FROM Creature WHERE uniquename='hildigrimTook';
LET $2 = SELECT expand(bothE(Begets)) FROM Creature WHERE uniquename='adalgrimTook';
LET $3 = SELECT INTERSECT($1, $2).size();
SELECT $3;
```

Returns 7 as expected but I get a Java null pointer exception when I try to run it in the IF statement

```
IF($3 > 0) {
    return 'Already present';
}
IF($3 == 0) {
    return $4;
}
```

Expected output would be for the script to return either 'Already present' or the @rid of the newly created edge.  Help appreciated, I've tried every which way I can think of and the documentation doesn't cover IF in much detail.

Comment: Did you try the size on `$3.intersect`? 
Since that is how you declared it and how it should be stored.

Comment: You mean `IF($3.INTERSECT.size()`?  I just tried it and neither of the `IF` functions were called, but calling `SELECT $3.INTERSECT.size()` returns 7 as expected.  I'm pretty consistently getting different behavior with `IF` that doesn't seem right

Comment: I'm not using any if structures myself so can't really help you out there, sorry

Comment: Folks, it seems to be a little bug in the executor, I'm working on it now

Comment: Thanks @LuigiDell'Aquila , sorry to crosspost here and in Github, I posted here first but realized it was probably a bug.

Comment: No problem, I pushed a fix already (bug tracked here https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/8263)